# Ubuntu is not booting in a windows 8.1 installed laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I recently bought a lap top with windows 8.1 already installed . I installed Ubuntu om my lap by creating free space using windows disk manager. i successfully installed ubuntu. But after restarting it does not show any boot menu to boot in to ubuntu. it directly entering to windows.

```
 My laptop is HP-r014-tx
```

The person who marked my question as duplicate please understand in that question his problem is different. He cant boot windows.. My problem is just reverese :(

Comment: His problem is just opposite to my problem

Comment: Check the troubleshooting part of this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/308164 There the problem is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 or F10 (check on the screen when Laptop starts booting) to enter BIOS menu.

From there, go to System Configuration and change boot order to put Ubuntu on top of Windows.

Save Changes and Exit. On restarting the computer, you'll see the GRUB Boot menu. From here, you can either select Ubuntu or Windows.

Hope this works.